# Exibir em ngModel retorno do FireStore

Tags: html, firebase, typescript, angular, angularjs-directives

### Como exibir os dados retornados do FireStore em uma diretiva do Angular ngModel?

Gostaria de pegar os dados que é retornado do FireStore e exibir em uma diretiva do Angular ngModel, exibindo em uma tela de edição.

**pessoa.model.ts:**

```
export class Pessoa {
    nome: string;
    telefone: string;
}
```

**pessoa.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Pessoa } from 'app/models/pessoa';

@Injectable()
export class PessoaService {

  pessoaDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  pessoasCursor: AngularFirestoreCollection<Pessoa>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.pessoasCursor = this.afs.collection('pessoas', ref => ref.orderBy('nome', 'asc'));
  }

  getValues(id?) {
    return this.pessoasCursor.valueChanges();
  }
```

**pessoa-view.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Pessoa} from 'app/models/pessoa';
import { PessoaService } from 'app/services/pessoa.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pessoa-edit',
  templateUrl: './pessoa-edit.component.html'
})
export class PessoaEditComponent implements OnInit {
  pessoaId: any;
  pessoa: any; // [(ngModel)]="pessoa.nome"

  constructor(private route: Router, private routeAct: ActivatedRoute,
  private pacienteService: PacienteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeAct.params.subscribe(params =>{
      this.pessoaId = params['id'];
    })

    // Retornar aqui apenas a pessoa com o ID
    this.pessoa = this.pessoaService.getValues(id);
  }

}
```

**pessoa-edit.component.html:**

```
<--! Aqui preciso exibir o nome que retornou do FireStore.-->

   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nome" formControlName="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você já tenha achado a solução mas para caso alguém precise, seu `this.pessoasCursor.valueChanges();` está retornando um `Observable`, é necessário se inscrever via `subscribe` para acessar seus valores, então:

```
this.pessoaService.getValues().subscribe(value => this.pessoa = value);
```

E no input do HTML mudar para `[(ngModel)]="pessoa.nome"` e remover o `formControlName="nome"` pois ele é para [formulários reativos](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Salientando que hoje seu `getValues` não está filtrando por Id e sim buscando todos as pessoas ordenadas pelo nome, vide:

```
this.afs.collection('pessoas', ref => ref.orderBy('nome', 'asc'));
```